# Google Now for GingerBread?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, google-now

Is it possible to get Google Now on old phones ? It really sounds amazing.I would love to try it out :)

I found this for ICS.  - http://techzei.com/get-google-now-on-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich/

Comment: Which phone do you have? I wonder if there is a third party ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod) which you could flash to get newer android features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Honeycomb and below is "dead" development, people are focused on doing more on ICS than anything.
When Eclair rolled out, development stopped on Cupcake and Donut, and now its quite hard to imagine someone still working on those old versions of Android. There may be around it involving rooting your phone but I doubt it. Look at your link, the third requirement: **Deodexed ROM**. That is part of what is holding older phones back. My suggestion would just be to upgrade your phone but i realize that is not an ideal solution. Sorry man.